# How can I return a list of integers that add up to a provided integer n

Tags: java, loops, math, integer

I have a function  `public static List<Integer> change(int n)` that takes in an integer n and returns how many times does ints 5,2 and 1 add up to `n` (it should use the minimum number of ints possible). For example

if `n = 12`, the output would be `[5,5,2]` since 5+5+2 = 12
if `n = 55`, the output would be `[5,5,5,5,5]` since 5+5+5+5+5 = 25.
if `n = 3`, the output would be `[2,1]` since 2+1 = 3.

I'm struggling to understand the logic behind implementing this into code, so here is what I have so far:

```
List<Integer> change(int n) {
    a = 5
    b = 2
    c = 1
    int[] j;
    if (a+b+c == n) {
         j.add(a)
         j.add(b)
         j.add(c) }
    }
```

Can someone please explain the logic behind tackling a problem like this so that I can make the necessary changes?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for the _Knapsack Problem_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. While `n>=5`: Add 5 to the list and set `n = n - 5`.
2. While `n>=2`: Add 2 to the list and set `n = n - 2`.
3. While `n>=1`: Add 1 to the list and set `n = n - 1`.
4. Return the list

Additionally, a list is not the same as an array and you need to use the correct constructor for it i.e.

```
List<Integer> j = new ArrayList<>();
```